# VB to SQL Power Of Calculation

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, excel, vba

I am trying to convert this calculation from VB into SQL, how would I go about this? -

`1.2 * 10 ^ -7`

The value it returns in the VB app is 0.00000012

I have tried the following with no success -

```
select (1.2 * power(10, -7))
select (power((1.2 * 10), -7))
```

Any help would be appreciated...
Thanks in advance

Comment: `select (1.2 * power(10, -7))` works for me.

Comment: It just returns 0 for me.. Strange. The answer below works anyway.

Comment: How about `SELECT 1.2E-7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select (1.2 / power(10, 7))
```